# What is the meaning of D(x,l) or D(x,f(x)) in here?

Tags: optimization

I was reading this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6199.pdf and I couldn't understand what `D(x,l)` means.

My interpretation of the objective function is as follows.

```
r : noise
x : image
l : label
```

Minimize the noisy image `r` such that its addition to the image `x` results in the new image being classified as `l`. The following sentence then uses the term `D(x,l)` and I still don't get what it means after spending some time reading it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally understood it. `D(x,l)` is the distortion function such that `x` is classified as l or intuitively, the intensity I need to add to each pixel such that the resulting image gets classified as `l`. That is why `D(x,f(x))` = `f(x)` because the distortion function to have `x` be classified as `f(x)` is simply `f(x)`